# Set color seekbar

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I'm creating a small paint android app using android studio java. I create in the menu an icon for changing the color of the drawing. Once the user click on it a new AlertDialog should appear showing 4 seekbars for ARGB colors. I ended with this code but I still don't know why it's not working. Can someone please help me?

```
private Drawing draws;

private SeekBar alphaSeekBar;
private SeekBar redSeekBar;
private SeekBar greenSeekBar;
private SeekBar blueSeekBar;

private void showColorDialog(){
    currentAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.color_dialog, null);
    alphaSeekBar = view.findViewById(R.id.alphaSeekBar);
    redSeekBar = view.findViewById(R.id.redSeekBar);
    greenSeekBar = view.findViewById(R.id.greenSeekBar);
    blueSeekBar = view.findViewById(R.id.blueSeekBar);
    colorView = view.findViewById(R.id.colorView);

    alphaSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(colorSeekBarChanged);
    redSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(colorSeekBarChanged);
    greenSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(colorSeekBarChanged);
    blueSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(colorSeekBarChanged);

    int color = draws.getDrawingColor();
    alphaSeekBar.setProgress(Color.alpha(color));
    redSeekBar.setProgress(Color.red(color));
    greenSeekBar.setProgress(Color.green(color));
    blueSeekBar.setProgress(Color.blue(color));

    Button setColorButton = view.findViewById(R.id.setColorButton);
    setColorButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            pikassoView.setDrawingColor(Color.argb(
                    alphaSeekBar.getProgress(),
                    redSeekBar.getProgress(),
                    greenSeekBar.getProgress(),
                    blueSeekBar.getProgress()
            ));

            colorDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    currentAlertDialog.setView(view);
    currentAlertDialog.setTitle("Choose color");
    colorDialog = currentAlertDialog.create();
    colorDialog.show();
}   private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener colorSeekBarChanged = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        draws.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(
                alphaSeekBar.getProgress(),
                redSeekBar.getProgress(),
                greenSeekBar.getProgress(),
                blueSeekBar.getProgress()
        ));


        colorView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(
                alphaSeekBar.getProgress(),
                redSeekBar.getProgress(),
                greenSeekBar.getProgress(),
                blueSeekBar.getProgress()
        ));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First, this `alphaSeekBar.setProgress(Color.alpha(color));` is wrong. setProgress is meant for setting int value to show how much progress seekbar has.

If your seekBar Max is set to 100 (`alphaSeekBar.setMax(100);`) then this `alphaSeekBar.setProgress(50);` means seekBar is progressed half way.

Second, to set colors use this:

```js
alphaSeekBar.setProgressTintList(Color.alpha(color));
alphaSeekBar.setThumbTintList(Color.alpha(color));
```

Or, use this:

```
alphaSeekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.alpha(color), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

try different tint modes in place of `PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY` to get your desired result

good luck

EDIT:

For setting a custom view to Alert Dialog

```js
currentAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
// ...Irrelevant code for customizing the buttons and title
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.color_dialog, null);
currentAlertDialog.setView(view);
```

then you can get those seekbar references like below:

```
alphaSeekBar = currentAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.alphaSeekBar);
redSeekBar = currentAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.redSeekBar);
greenSeekBar = currentAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.greenSeekBar);
blueSeekBar = currentAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.blueSeekBar);
colorView = currentAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.colorView);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The app still don't work.

Comment: Your welcome, did you apply my answer to all of your code? All of your codes need to be changed, all seekbar.setProgress lines need to change. Of course it doesn't work

Comment: If you have no logcat Try commenting out some lines to find mistakes

Comment: I have changed all the seekbar.setProgress. This is the mistake:
Process: com.pairz.drawing, PID: 3477
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #111: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: this is an xml layout issue. I have edited the answer. look if it works.

Comment: you need to add 'currentAlertDialog.setView(view);' below the inflate method

Comment: your welcome would appreciate an upvote on the answer. thanks